# Find the inverse using fast exponential algorithm?

Tags: divisibility

I need to solve the following equation:

$$x\equiv 17^{-1} \pmod{83}$$

Using...some "fast exponential algorithm". Well, that's the only information I have. Do you maybe know some fast exponential algorithm that could be helpful? ;)

Comment: $83$ is prime, and for primes $p$ you have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ when $p$ doesn't divide $a$, hence the modular inverse of $a$ is given by $a^{p-2}$ (modulo $p$). But here, it's faster to note that $5\cdot 17 = 85 \equiv 2 \pmod{83}$, hence $17^{-1} = 5\cdot 2^{-1}$ and that becomes $(5+83)/2 = 44$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Diego mentions, because $83$ is prime, [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) yields
$$
17^{81}\equiv17^{-1}\pmod{83}
$$
Since $81=1010001_{\text{two}}$, we can compute $17^{81}\pmod{83}$ by repeated squaring and multiplication:
$$
\begin{align}
17^0&\equiv1&&\text{initial}&&0000000\\
17^1&\equiv17&&\times17&&0000001&&\text{add $1$ to the exponent}\\
17^2&\equiv40&&\text{square}&&0000010&&\text{double the exponent}\\
17^4&\equiv23&&\text{square}&&0000100&&\text{double the exponent}\\
17^5&\equiv59&&\times17&&0000101&&\text{add $1$ to the exponent}\\
17^{10}&\equiv78&&\text{square}&&0001010&&\text{double the exponent}\\
17^{20}&\equiv25&&\text{square}&&0010100&&\text{double the exponent}\\
17^{40}&\equiv44&&\text{square}&&0101000&&\text{double the exponent}\\
17^{80}&\equiv27&&\text{square}&&1010000&&\text{double the exponent}\\
17^{81}&\equiv44&&\times17&&1010001&&\text{add $1$ to the exponent}\\
\end{align}
$$
To check
$$
17\times44\equiv1\pmod{83}
$$

Answer (score 4):

[Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) takes $O(log(n))$ time, where $n$ is the exponent.

Because $83$ is a prime number, you can use the fact that $x^{-1}\equiv x^{p-2} (mod \space p)$ where $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: More accurately, it takes $O(\log n)$ modular multiplies. For a fixed modulus that means $O(\log n)$ time, but if we let the modulus vary, then the time depends on the modulus as well!

Answer (score 1):

You already have answers, let us now try another approach. All the following is done via arithmetic modulo $\;83\;$:

$$17=-66=(-11)\cdot 6$$

$$\begin{align*}6\cdot 14&=84=1\implies 6^{-1}=14\\{}\\
11\cdot7&=77=-6\implies 11^{-1}=-6^{-1}\cdot7=-14\cdot7=-98=-15=68\end{align*}$$

So finally

$$17^{-1}=(-11)^{-1}\cdot 6^{-1}=15\cdot14=15\cdot7\cdot2=22\cdot2=44$$